# Replace pandas iterrows with vectorization/apply

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Consider the following example where I am going through each row, split them in two samples and execute a statistical test per each row:

```
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        stat, p = mannwhitneyu(row.iloc[:self.neighbors], row.iloc[self.neighbors:], alternative = 'greater')
        data.loc[index, 'stat'] = stat
        data.loc[index, 'prob'] = p
```

Is there is any way to speed this up? I saw that Apply or Vectorization should improve it, but I don't really know how it can be implemented with respect to what I am trying to achieve as I need to execute the same test row by row.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly does `mannwhitneyu` do?

Comment: Hi @mrzo it's a non-parametric statistical test that checks whether the samples X and Y are coming from the same population or not. It's a scipy statistical function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html

Answer (score 0):

You can apply to rows if you specify `axis=1`. In your case it would be something like this:

```
def change_value(row):
    stat, p = mannwhitneyu(row.iloc[:self.neighbors], row.iloc[self.neighbors:], 
    alternative = 'greater')
    row['stat'] = stat
    row['prob'] = p

#Assuming your dataframe is called df
df.apply(change_value, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, interestingly when implementing apply function my algorithm is running even slower than before... Do you think there is some sort of vectorized version for this?

Comment: That's surprising. Well the most obvious thing when it comes to speed is to use numpy arrays. That'll get rid of pandas overhead. Maybe check out how you can use arrays in your usecase